# Correlation between color of light visible to us and the intensity of transmitted light by the material

Tags: optics, visible-light

I wanted to know if there is any relation between the color of light observed by the eye and the intensity of light transmitted by a material.
Let us assume that I have a table of intensities of light transmitted at different wavelengths by a material for 2 materials.
Is it possible to determine which material will appear more colored and which is that color?
I know that if a material transmits with more intensity at the wavelength of green light, it would be more 'greener' but what will be the effect of a range of wavelengths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect would be exactly the same as how we perceive color in general. Most object around us are not monochromatic reflectors i.e. they don't reflect a single wavelength of light, rather they reflect a range of wavelengths, with different intensities associated with different wavelengths.

Thus is it not only possible, but also relatively easy to determine the color of the material given such a table.

You could create a simple simulation on a computer by mapping each wavelength on your (hypothetical) table to its approximate RGB color. Weighting each color by its fractional intensity and adding them together would give you an idea of what you might expect for material's color.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and there is a standard way to compute this. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931). First start with the 3 functions (roughly corresponding to the 3 types of cones in the eye) pictured below
[image: tristimulus values]

Now given the [spectral power distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_power_distribution) $I(\lambda)$ (i.e. your table of light at each wavelength) compute the "tristimulus values" for a color given by
$$ X= \int_{380}^{780} I(\lambda)\,\overline{x}(\lambda)\,d\lambda,\quad
Y= \int_{380}^{780} I(\lambda)\,\overline{y}(\lambda)\,d\lambda,\quad\text{and }
Z= \int_{380}^{780} I(\lambda)\,\overline{z}(\lambda)\,d\lambda,$$
where wavelengths are given in nm. Now normalize the variables
$$x=\frac{X}{X+Y+Z},\quad y=\frac{Y}{X+Y+Z},\quad\text{and } z=\frac{Z}{X+Y+Z}.$$
$x$ and $y$ can be used to give you the color as shown in the chart below.

[image: color]